# including php files with exec-PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed and activated the execPHP plug in and used this

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
<?php include ("/test/test.php") ?>
```

in the tinyMCE of wordpress.

I get to see the hello outputted properly, but then I see this error;

> Warning: include(/test/test.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\5291199\html\sites\Main\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 3
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening ‘/test/test.php’ for inclusion (include_path=’.;C:\php5\pear’) in D:\Hosting\5291199\html\sites\Main\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 3

I know for sure, `/test/test.php` exists! It's got valid php code...

Comment: Just to make sure, you have a file `D:\test\test.php`? The first `/` makes it look for it in the root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a full path

```
echo dir(__FILE__); // Find out in what folder you are
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/../test/test.php"); // then adjust to the location of the file from this path
```

Comment: If you have PHP 5.3 or later you can use the `__DIR__` constant.
If you have an older PHP version you should use `dirname(__FILE__)`

`dir(...)` returns an instance of `Directory`

Comment: sorry, i meant dirname :-) tnx

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) returns D:\Hosting\5291199\html\sites\Main\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes

Comment: Ok, so that's your starting point. In what folder is `test.php`? As per my answer, from the folder you are in, you can go up folders by prepending `../` to the `dirname`. E.g. include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/../test/test.php");

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?> returns D:\\Hosting\\5291199\\html    You're on the right track Richard. Isn't there a utility in PHP where I can say gimmefullpath($a_virtual_path_here). In asp, we got server.mappath with which you can do server.mappath("/test/test.asp") and this gets you d:/whatever/whatever/test/test.php

Comment: You can just as well use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as starting point. Might even be better (in case the plugin path changes for whatever reason). In what (absolute file) is test.php? Does this work: `include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/test.php" );` ??

Comment: `Server.MapPath(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO"))` is basically the same as `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: $path = "/test/test.php"; 
    $fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
    echo $fullpath;
    //and with that I get this; 
    D:\\Hosting\\5291199\\html/test/test.php
    what's the real alternative to the following one liner in PHP?
    
    include (fullpath("/test/test.php"));

Comment: i am not in need of a situation like the path_info would help. I'm including a file using a virtual path...  also, the document_root returns a path with \ slashes escape, does that mean I should pad my full path as follows; $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\\test\\test.php". I'm looking for a simple & clean way out like I mentioned above, we've got to have a simple built in php function that returns the full path ( starting all the way from the d: ) when used like this fullpath("/whatever.php"). If I can find that function, I'll be done.

Comment: The one-liner is `include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/test.php" );` which I posted. You could use `include( fullpath("/test/test.php") );`, but then you would need to make a `function` called `fullpath` that creates the string..

Comment: I don't mind making that function but I find it surprising that php does not come with one... you sure php does not have a function like this. i've searched manual, tried basename realpath etc... they all do other things... aaaa the good old server.mappath! where are you?

Comment: Backslashes in strings need to be escaped, the reason this is happening is that you are on a Windows machine. PHP on Windows will accept `D:\\Hosting\\5291199\\html/test/test.php`. PHP on Linux will not accept `/path/to/file\\test\\test.php`. I would recommend simply using `include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/test.php" )`, if you want you can use/create the function `fullpath`, but doesn't add much value..